# Pytest unit test fails because target function has cachetools.ttl_cache decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a function that I am writing unit tests for using pytest. The only problem is that since I am writing multiple tests for the same function, a couple of tests fail because of the cachetools.ttl_cache decorator. This decorator makes the function return the same value every time it is being run which messes up the tests. This decorator is not present in the function that I am testing but in a function that is called by the one that I am testing. I cannot remove this decorator from the function I am testing. Here is the test:

```
@patch('load_balancer.model_helpers.DBSession')
def test_returns_true_if_split_test_is_external(self, dbsession, group_ctx):
    group_ctx.group_id = '{}-{}'.format('2222222222', '123456789')
    split_test = Mock()
    split_test.state = 'external'
    config = {
        'query.return_value.filter.return_value.first.return_value': split_test
    }
    dbsession.configure_mock(**config)
    assert group_ctx.is_in_variation_group('foo') == True
```

And here is the function to be tested:

```
def is_in_variation_group(self, split_test=None):
    try:
        split_test = get_split_test(split_test) # This function has the 
        #decorator
        log.info('Split test {} is set to {}'.format(split_test.name,
                                                     split_test.state))
        if not split_test or split_test.state == 'off':
            return False

        phone_number = int(self.group_id.split('-')[0])
        if split_test.state == 'internal':
            return True if str(phone_number) in INTERNAL_GUINEA_PIGS else False
        if split_test.state == 'external':
            return True if phone_number % 2 == 0 else False
    except Exception as e:
        log.warning("A {} occurred while evaluating membership into {}'s variation "
                    "group".format(e.__class__.__name__, split_test))
```

Get split test function:

```
    @cachetools.ttl_cache(maxsize=1024, ttl=60)
    def get_split_test(name):
         return (DBSession.query(SplitTest)
                 .filter(SplitTest.name == name)
                 .first())
```

How can I make it so this cache decorator is ignored? Any help is appreciated greatly

Comment: I think you need to patch `cachetools` before running tests and replace `ttl_cache` with a function that doesn't cache anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest clearing the function's cache after each test run.

The [cachetools documentation](http://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cachetools.func.ttl_cache) doesn't mention this, but from [the source code](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/blob/master/cachetools/func.py#L69) it appears the cache decorators expose a `cache_clear` function.

For your example code under test:

```
import cachetools.func

@cachetools.func.ttl_cache(maxsize=1024, ttl=60)
def get_split_test(name):
     return (DBSession.query(SplitTest)
             .filter(SplitTest.name == name)
             .first())
```

This would be my approach (assumes pytest >= 3, otherwise use the `yield_fixture` decorator):

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def clear_cache():
    yield
    get_split_test.cache_clear()

def test_foo():
    pass # Test your function like normal.
```

That `clear_cache` fixture uses a yield fixture that is automatically used after each test (`autouse=True`) to perform the cleanup after each test. You also can use [the `request` fixture and `request.addfinalizer`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) to run a cleanup function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am getting this error when I run that fixture above: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clear_cache'` Is there any other way to clear the cache?

Comment: Whoops, I reversed it, it's `cache_clear()`. I'll update my answer.

BTW unless you're running a different version of cachetools, your example should show `cachetools.func.ttl_cache` as the decorator. I tested out cachetools version 2.0.0

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Thanks so much

Comment: Note in cachetools version `3.0.0` the method is `.clear()` instead of `cache_clear()`

Comment: I have the same issue except my function is `async def get_split_test` - how can we deal with the async function?

Answer (score 2):

I would assign the cache into a variable and then at the end of the test reset the cache

```py
GET_USERS_CACHE = TTLCache(maxsize=128, ttl=60)

@cached(cache=GET_USERS_CACHE)
def get_users():
    pass
```

test file

```py
def test_get_users():
    # test code here
    GET_USERS_CACHE.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @Frank_T's answer I was getting an error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clear_cache'`

Another approach I tried was to split the cached function into two functions:

```
    @cachetools.ttl_cache(maxsize=1024, ttl=60)
    def get_split_test(name):
         return (DBSession.query(SplitTest)
                 .filter(SplitTest.name == name)
                 .first())
```

becomes

```
    @cachetools.ttl_cache(maxsize=1024, ttl=60)
    def get_split_test(name):
         return get_split_test_uncached(name)

    def get_split_test_uncached(name):
         return (DBSession.query(SplitTest)
                 .filter(SplitTest.name == name)
                 .first())
```

Then, test the `get_split_test_uncached` function. It is not as tidy as I would like, but it gets the job done.